# Не подгружается HTML страница Vue3 + Vite

Tags: vue.js, vite

Учусь писать на **Vue** и использую **Vite**. Создал тестовый проект, настроил `vite.config.js`, создал необходимую мне структуру файлов и папок (предполагается многостраничный вебсайт). Запускаю сервер через `npm run dev`, ошибок нет. Перехожу на локалхост, но моей HTML страницы там нет. Посмотрел во вкладке network, там кроме иконки ничего нет. Подумал что неправильно указал путь. Но команда `npm run build` корректно находит все файлы и создаёт всё что нужно. Ниже прикрепил все необходимые файлы, буду благодарен за помощь!

Структура папок:

```
website/
├─ dist/
├─ node_modules/
├─ src/
│  ├─ grenades/
│  │  ├─ assets/
│  │  ├─ components/
│  │  ├─ grenades.html
│  │  ├─ grenades.js
│  │  ├─ Grenades.vue
├─ package.json
├─ vite.config.js
```

vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

const root = resolve(__dirname, 'src')
const outDir = resolve(__dirname, 'dist')

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  root,
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {
    outDir,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        grenades: resolve(root, 'grenades', 'grenades.html'),
      },
    },
  }
})
```

grenades.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <p>text</p>
    <script type="module" src="./grenades.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

grenades.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Grenades from '@/grenades/Grenades.vue'

createApp(Grenades).mount('#app')
```

Grenades.vue

```
<template>
  <h1>All works!</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: vite.config.js:
добавь:
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler',
        },
    },